# Workbox precache putting items inside -temp cache, and not using it later

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I stumbled upon a problem I'm struggling with for two days now and I can't make it work.

I'm trying to precache a few api calls using Google Workbox plugin for service worker.

My code looks like this:

```
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

const precacheController = new workbox.precaching.PrecacheController();

self.addEventListener("install", event => {
  const assetsLoaded = fetch("http://localhost:8000/pages")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      let pagesList = response.map(
        page =>
          `http://localhost:8000/pages?slug=${page.slug}`
      );
      pagesList.push("http://localhost:8000/frontpage");
      precacheController.addToCacheList(pagesList);
    })
    .then(() => {
      precacheController.install();
    });
  event.waitUntil(assetsLoaded);
});

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

It's based on code shown in this thread: [Service worker add files from API call to precache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651002/service-worker-add-files-from-api-call-to-precache)

I can see in inspector that those requests are firing and are stored in `workbox-precache-http://localhost:3001/-temp` cache. But parallel to this cache, I see that there is `workbox-precache-http://localhost:3001/` cache created, which is empty.

Also, in `workbox-precache-http://localhost:3001/-temp` i can see that every cached response has `Content-Length: 0`. I don't know why but this could be a clue. Although when I look at given response I can see its full content in inspector...

When I try making some api call which should be precached, it won't use cached response but makes new request instead. In offline mode, this causes an error.

My goal is to have those request stored in cache so user can browse through whole page offline.

What am I doing wrong?